# More than one file type in Uploadify

Tags: javascript, jquery, customization, uploadify

I'm searching for a solution for havinig different file types in the jQuery plugin [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/).

Think about the following prozedure: You want to open a file with a program of your choice. Starting with a default OS-Dialog you can select different file types in a dropdown menu splitted in different extensions for their types. For example audio files (*.mp3, *.ogg), image files (*.jpeg, *.gif), etc. I know the options `fileExt` and `fileDesc` but I can't find the right way to implement this special feature with this options.

I also know [FancyUpload](http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/) for mootools, where I can define different types, but don't want to use a second framework for JavaScript.

Thanks for your help.
Lemmi

Comment: ok so you want the dropdown to be available in the file upload dialogue?

Comment: Yip, with more than one option.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
       // <![CDATA[
       $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#fileInput').uploadify({
       'uploader': 'uploadify/uploadify.swf',
       'script': 'Upload.ashx',
       'scriptData': { 'id': 1, 'foo': 'test'},
       'cancelImg': 'uploadify/cancel.png',
       'auto': true,
       'multi': true,
       'fileDesc': 'Image Files', //<-- This can be whatever you want
       'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.png;*.gif;*.bmp;*.jpeg',  //<-- Answer Here
       'queueSizeLimit': 90,
       'sizeLimit': 4000000,
       'buttonText': 'Choose Images',
       'folder': '/uploads',
       'onAllComplete': function(event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) {

       }
     });
   });
   // ]]>
  </script>

   <input id="fileInput" name="fileInput" type="file" />
```

Comment: This would cause a single option in the drop down menu of the file upload dialog of the browser. But I'm looking for a solution having more than one filetype.

Comment: I gotcha...Don't think you can do that with uploadify. =/  Unless they have had an update since I last checked on it.

Comment: Its not possible currently - My suggestion would be to ask the guys at uploadify if that is something they would consider implementing..